# Unauthorized source IP address With facebook sdk

Tags: facebook, sdk

My site uses the "facebook api sdk" to access the users facebook information and then log them in.

The following error message is produced: "Error: Could not access the Facebook API client (failed on users_getInfo(693671783)). Result: ; OAuthException: (#5) Unauthorized source IP address". I have tried using a different facebook plugin (Nextend Facebook Connect) , but the same error message is produced.

i tried to fill IP Address whitelist in App Setting, but still does not work...

Comment: Please post some code to demonstrate an example of what you're doing. It's almost impossible to help you debug without knowing what you're actually calling.

Comment: have posted a step by step guide to resolve this issue, https://apoorv.quora.com/OAuthException-Unauthorized-source-IP-address-Facebook-Application Hope it helps..

Answer (score 4):

**Are you using Heroku?**

If you are, your server outgoing IP will keep changing every time you deploy, some of Herokus IPs are blacklisted by Facebook so its really a random thing that will happen depending on which server you get at the time.

Fixing your outgoing IP with something like **[Proximo](https://addons.heroku.com/proximo)** will make your source IP predictable when you query the API but its a bit pricy.

If you have a small app with a single dyno you can just keep recycling with `heroku ps:restart` until you get one of the 'good' servers.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple instances ( Dynos and Workers ), likely not all of them are blacklisted.  Running 'heroku ps:restart' could move some of your good instances to bad IPs.  Instead I recommend recycling only the bad instances through

```
heroku restart bad_instance_name --app=your_app_name
```

You can find the instances by grepping

```
heroku logs -t --app=your_app_name | grep 'Unauthorized source IP address'
```

The resulting output will reveal the instance names.

This worked much better for us than 'heroku ps:restart' since we have more than 5 running instances, and at any one time only 1 or 2 of them had a bad IP.

Comment: FB has updated their bug as 'Fixed' for this issue. See https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/649166715098648